# Влияет ли import на производительность?

Tags: java

Если я вместо import java.util.Arrays; сразу напишу import java.util.*; , это как-то повлияет на производительность?

Comment: Нет. Это говорит лишь то, что вы импортируете все зависимости из  java.util

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не влияет. Никак.

Код обработает компилятор, он пройдется по всем используемым классам и пропишет их в байткоде. После компиляции строк `import` уже не будет.

Т.е. вот этот класс:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public Date date;
}
```

Для компилятора эквивалентен этому:

```
public class Main {
  public java.util.Date date;
}
```

В JDK есть утилита [`javap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), которая декомпилиурет `.class`-файлы. Можете поэкспериментировать с ней чтобы проверить что `import`-ов после компиляции не остается.

Теоретически импорты могут повлиять на время работы компилятора, но скорее всего это влияние будет пренебрежимо мало.

Comment: `будет пренебрежимо мало` - это сильное утверждение, ибо все относительно (железо, память, версия Java, количество подобных импортов, объем кода)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin поэтому и пишу «скорее всего». Мне сложно представить ситуацию в которой именно «звездочки» будут узким местом, но все возможно.

Comment: Узким местом они не будут, точно ). Фраза `время сборки будет пренебрежимо мало` не корректна, почему - я уже сказал раньше

Comment: @AlexanderChernin У меня этой фразы нет :) Если последнее предложение некорректно, то не могли бы Вы предложить свой вариант? Я был бы за это очень благодарен.

Comment: Да, точнее `Время работы компилятора пренебрежимо мало`. Свой вариант я уже высказал

Comment: @AlexanderChernin у меня написано «...скорее всего это [импортов] **влияние** будет пренебрежимо мало ... » Я не понял что Вам не нравится, ну да и ладно, бывает. :) Спасибо за комментарий!